# c# linq keep only matching dictionary values based on list

Tags: c#, linq

I have one composite dictionary and one list

```
Dictionary<Point, List<int>> GroupedIndex
int[] TobeMatched
```

Now I want to check for every key, whether there are any matching values in the TobeMatched array. If it is matching, then keep only matching values for that key and remove other values. If there is no match, then delete the key.

```
Example:

GroupedIndex: [0] -> Key [X=1;Y=1]; Values [0] -> 5, [1] -> 10
              [1] -> Key [X=1;Y=2]; Values [0] -> 1, [1] -> 3, [2] -> 6
TobeMatched: {1,2,6}

Result expected:
New dictionary: [0] -> Key[X=1;Y=2]; Values [0] -> 1, [1] -> 6
```

is it possible to achieve this in linq?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to modify your original dictionary with LINQ, because LINQ is composed of pure operations (i.e. does not mutate the values it works on).

With pure LINQ it is possible to simply get a new dictionary with your specifications:

```
var newGroupedIndex = GroupedIndex
    .Select(pair => new { 
                        Key = pair.Key, 
                        Matched = pair.Value.Intersect(TobeMatched).ToList()
                        })
    .Where(o => o.Matched.Count != 0)
    .ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Matched);
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/seJ3c)**.

Comment: Hello Jon, I was using the above code which works if the dataset is around 10,000 count but for reasonably large dataset, Systemoutofmemory exception has been thrown. Any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: @Suresh: Yes: rewrite your program to not try and fit all the data in memory at once.

Comment: I dont know how do I do that! Can I iterate groupedindex list one by one and add newGroupedIndex?